# Locate Java standard library

Tags: java, python, classpath

What is the best way to locate the jar containing core Java classes such as `java.lang.Object`? I have been using `JAVA_HOME`, but it turns out that that only works if the JDK is installed. How can I just find the standard library location that would be used if `java` were run from the commandline?

Also, I need to do this from a Python script, so please don't respond with Java libraries.

Answer (score 2):

When you launch `java` from Oracle's JVM, it sets `sun.boot.class.path` property to point to `rt.jar`, which normally contains all the `java.lang` stuff.

What you could do is to launch a simple Java program which retrieves `System.getProperty("sun.boot.class.path")` and gets where this file is supposed to be. Read more on this [here](http://www.tedneward.com/files/Papers/BootClasspath/BootClasspath.pdf).

Above should work if your environment is correct (`JAVA_HOME` is set, etc.). Otherwise, I'm afraid you have chicken and egg problem ;-)

Comment: While this is a nice and creative approach, the `sun.boot.class.path` property is only present on Sun's JVM implementation.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid needing to run a separate program.

Answer (score 1):

Since there are no explicit restrictions on placing internal classes, then you should try handle all the possible (or as much as possible) places.

First of all, you should definitely look for `java` in PATH. Unfortunately, it will fail sometimes, for instance, you can often find `java.exe` in `C:\Windows\System32`. Fortunately, in case of Windows you can use registry to get a list of installed JREs.

If you have found some jars which might contain basic classes, you can use `zip` or `jar` to check that `java/lang/Object.class` is there.

Comment: JREs can be found simply using `JAVA_HOME`. The issue is that there often isn't one installed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using linux, you can use shell command: "type java" and parse output.

Answer (score 0):

Python should have the means to find the location of "java" or "java.exe" executable.  Follow all symbolic links to reveal the true location.  My Python is rusty, but I think `shutil.which` and `os.path.realpath` will do the job.

The core classes will be in `../lib/rt.jar` relative to the java executable.

Comment: Except when they aren't, e.g. on Apple JDKs for Mac OS which use `Classes.jar`

Comment: `shutil.which` looks like it would work great, except that it is 3.3 only.

Comment: I was wrong and Ian is right:  Assuming the existence of rt.jar would not work on all platforms anyway.